# How to make regex that can take at most one asterisk in character class?

Tags: regex

I want to create a regular expression that match a string that starts with an optional minus sign `-` and ends with a minus sign. In between must begin with a letter (upper or lower case) which can be followed by any combination of letters, numbers and may, at most, contain one asterix (*)

So far I have came up with this

```
[-]?[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9(*{0,1})]*[-]
```

Some examples of what I am trying to achieve.

```
"-yyy-" // valid
"-u8r*y75-" // valid
"-u8r**y75-" // invalid
```

Comment: How does your question relate to Java, JavaScript and Python 3.x?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/uKzoBz/1)

```
^-?[a-z](?!(?:.*\*){2})[a-z\d*]*-$
```

Alternatively, you can use the following regex to achieve the same results without using a negative lookahead.

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/uKzoBz/2)

```
^-?[a-z][a-z\d]*(?:\*[a-z\d]*)?-$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
** VALID **
-yyy-
-u8r*y75-

** INVALID **
-u8r**y75-
```

#### Output

```
-yyy-
-u8r*y75-
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `-?` Match zero or one of the hyphen character `-`
- `[a-z]` Match a single ASCII alpha character between `a` and `z`. Note that the `i` modifier is turned on, thus this will also match uppercase variations of the same letters
- `(?!(?:.*\*){2})` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

  - `(?:.*\*){2}` Match an asterisk `*` twice
- `[a-z\d*]*` Match any ASCII letter between `a` and `z`, or a digit, or the asterisk symbol `*` literally, any number of times
- `-` Match this character literally
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: ohh,, my bad, giving +1 man,, it works like a clock.. swiss :)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a simpler way to do it with the negative look ahead?

Comment: @cod3min3 you can use `(?!.*\*.*\*)` instead of `(?!(?:.*\*){2})` but that's about it. I just find the original method is easier to understand: easier differentiation for all the asterisks `*` and it's also easily scalable - you can change `2` to `3` for example.

Comment: I made a mistake in my question. I was meant to say "without" the negative look ahead?

Comment: @cod3min3 I've edited my answer to include another alternative without a lookahead. If you need to make it scalable, you need to change the `?` at the end to `{0,2}` (this would allow 2 asterisks `*`)

Comment: @cod3min3 the second regex in my answer doesn’t use a lookahead

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
-(((\w|\d)*)(\*?)((\w|\d)*))-
```

You can try it here:
https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
(-)?(\w)+(\*(?!\*)|\w+)(-)
```

I used grouping to make it more clear. I changed `[a-zA-Z0-9]` to `\w` which stands for the same.
`(\*(?!\*)|\w+)`

This is the important change. Explained in words:
If it is a star `\*` and the preceding char was not a star`(?!\*)` (called negative lookahead = look at the preceding part) or if it is `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

Use this site to test: https://regexr.com/

They have a pretty good explaination on the left menu under "Reference".